# t sql max() in where clause

Tags: t-sql, max

I'm trying to use a `MAX(InvoiceDate)` in my where clause:

```
SELECT a.Customer,
       a.Name,
       b.Name,
       a.Branch,
       a.Area,
       MAX(e.InvoiceDate)
FROM   Customers a
       LEFT JOIN Rep b
         ON a.Salesperson = b.Salesperson
            AND a.Branch = b.Branch
       LEFT JOIN Sales e
         ON e.Customer = a.Customer
WHERE  max(e.InvoiceDate) >= '2013-11-01'
GROUP  BY a.Customer,
          a.Name,
          b.Name,
          a.Branch,
          a.Area
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking aggregates need to be referenced in the `HAVING`.

```
HAVING max(e.InvoiceDate) >= '2013-11-01'
```

But in this case you can just use

```
WHERE  e.InvoiceDate >= '2013-11-01'
```

There is no point using a `LEFT JOIN` here either as the condition turns it back into an `INNER` one.

Answer (score 0):

`please try`

```
with cte as
    (
    SELECT a.Customer,
           a.Name,
           b.Name,
           a.Branch,
           a.Area,
           MAX(e.InvoiceDate) as xx
    FROM   Customers a
           LEFT JOIN Rep b
             ON a.Salesperson = b.Salesperson
                AND a.Branch = b.Branch
           LEFT JOIN Sales e
             ON e.Customer = a.Customer
    GROUP  BY a.Customer,
              a.Name,
              b.Name,
              a.Branch,
              a.Area 
    )

    select * from cte where xx >='2013-11-01'
```

Answer (score 0):

two way, or use cte / subquery approach, or having instead of where:
here an example

```
Declare @Customers as table (Customer varchar(100),Name varchar(200),InvoiceDate datetime);
insert into @Customers values( '1','asd','2012-01-01');
insert into @Customers values( '1','asd','2012-01-02');
insert into @Customers values( '2','asd','2012-01-03');
insert into @Customers values( '2','asd','2012-01-04');
insert into @Customers values( '3','asd','2012-01-05');

SELECT Customer ,MAX(InvoiceDate)
FROM @Customers
GROUP  BY Customer
Having  max(InvoiceDate) > '2012-01-03'

select * 
from (
SELECT Customer ,MAX(InvoiceDate) InvoiceMax
FROM @Customers
GROUP  BY Customer) xxx
where InvoiceMax > '2012-01-03'
```